# Destroying Admob Ads Libgdx

Tags: android, admob

Without ads I find my game data 120 kb but after showing ads data become 1.6 mb

Here what I did to destroy ads:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    adView.destroy();
}
```

Comment: ads are loaded from the internet so its normal that it causes data traffic. Think of video ads which load an entire video from the internet. So the only thing you could do is to switch to non-video ads or remove them completely from your app.

Comment: I am asking if I can do something else than what I've done to destroy ads and reduce data size

Answer (score 0):

The extra data is almost certainly in your web cache as that is where Admob will cache ad artefacts. You could try clearing it.